# How to group words of a string into different strings using pre-defined word groups in python?

Tags: python, string, cpu-word

I would like to convert a string which contains words like this: The Red Fox The Cat The Dog Is Blue, into 3 strings which would contain The Red Fox for the first one, The Cat for the second and The Dog Is Blue for the last one.
More simply explained, it should do like so:

```py
#    String0 = The Red Fox The Cat The Dog Is Blue
# The line above should transform to the lines below
#    String1 = The Red Fox
#    String2 = The Cat
#    String3 = The Dog Is Blue
```

You must note that the words that form the expressions are meant to change (but still forming known expressions) so I was thinking about making a dictionary which would help to recognize the words and define how they should group together if it is possible.

I hope that I am understandable and that someone will have the answer to my question.

Comment: In this example, just split your strings on "The "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
import re

string = "The Red Fox The Cat The Dog Is Blue"
# create a regex by joining your words using pipe (|)
pattern = "(The(\\s(Red|Fox|Cat|Dog|Is|Blue))+)"  
print([x[0] for x in re.findall(pattern, string)])  # ['The Red Fox', 'The Cat', 'The Dog Is Blue']
```

In the above example, you can dynamically create your pattern from a list of words that you have.

EDIT: Dynamically constructing the pattern:

```
pattern = f"(The(\\s({'|'.join(list_of_words)}))+)"
```

Comment: I see. You can update your pattern to add the additional words: `pattern = "(The(\s(Red|Fox|Cat|Dog|Is|Blue|White|Elephant))+)"`

Comment: Since you have a list of words. The pattern should be created dynamically from your list. The code is just an example.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate. Your explanations helped me but what if I want to get the same result but this time changing the original string : admit than instead of having The Red Fox The Cat The Dog Is Blue, i have The Red Fox The Cat The White Elephant.I need a script which work with both original string.
I explane what I have in mind : In my script, I use requests and BeautifulSoup modules to get specific informations from a website, but these informations are meant to change everyday. However I know what form they can have so I can write every chunk of words there could be.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter instead of Shift + Enter and sent my comment before it was finished :/

Comment: Do you want to dynamically create the pattern right? You can do something like this:
`pattern = f"(The(\\s({'|'.join(list_of_words)}))+)"`

Comment: I will try by my side what you're saying, i will keep you posted.

Comment: After doing several researches in the regex documentation, I finally found the solution to my problem helping me with your answers, the final script is :
```regex = r"Expression 1|Expression 2|Expression 3|ect"
test_str = (x)
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))```
Where x is the output from the first part of my script.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you what you need, the basic code:

```
def separate():
    string0 = "The Red Fox The Cat The Dog Is Blue"
    sentences = ["The "+sentence.strip() for sentence in string0.lower().split("the") if sentence != ""]
    for sentence in sentences:
        print(sentence)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunatly it doesn't work for me :/